# How to assign all elements with a certain tag to a certain class?

Tags: css, class

In CSS, i have:

```
.white {color:white}
```

In HTML, i have:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div>Text here</div>
    <div>Text here</div>
    <div>Text here</div>
<div>
```

And I want all divs in the "foo" div to be in the class "white" without having to write it explicitly in every div. How is this property called and how do I write it in the CSS?

Thank you!

Comment: At this point, just adding the class white to the div with class foo, has the same result as adding the class white to all underlying divs, since these are child divs. So applying it just to the div foo works what you try to achive, which is the text color to white.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add the class declaratively, but the CSS rule

```
.foo > div {
    color:white
}
```

will match all `div`s that are direct descendants of something of class `foo`: (I changed the property for my example, because otherwise you can't see anything:)

```css
.white, .foo > div {
    background-color: blue
  }
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div>Line 1</div>
  <div>Line 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS preprocessors like `sass` or `less` can help you with their own mechanisms so you don't have to have a long enumeration of places your rule applies. (Look for "mixins" or "inheritance" in their docs.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of answering your question that I can think of off the top of my head.

1) using [JQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/oufxr1jg/), you could add the white class to all children of the foo div element.

2) add the white class to the foo class div element, which will cascade the style down to all child elements, hence cascading style sheet..

`<div class="foo white">
    <div>Text here</div>
    <div>Text here</div>
    <div>Text here</div>
<div>`